# How to override inline !important located inside multiple css id and classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, inline

I want to override an inline !important stored inside multiple css id and classes. Consider the following scenario:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C">
            <div id="D" class="column left">Swing Over Bed</div>
                <div class="row" style="background: blue !important;">650mm</div>
                <div class="column left">Swing In Gap</div>
                <div class="column right">800mm</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I searched around and found jQuery to be one possible solution. But, it didn't work for my needs:

```
 $(".row").attr("style", "red !important;");
```

Comment: basically there is no way to override it would basically altering it. Your code is not correct other than you are setting the style attribute with invalid CSS.

Comment: This fiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/wk0mtLq2/

Comment: *"But, it didn't work for my needs:"* So what are your needs? Something "works", but it does not meet your needs. I assume we should know why it does not work for you.

Comment: @epascarello, meaning, I can see that the code works for other people, but it doesn't work on my environment. So, I was wondering if there are other methods of overriding an inline !important (i.e., JavaScript as opposed to condensed jquery)

Comment: What is your environment, what is different? When are you running code? How is the html being added? My guess is, you are not running the code at the right time. Only way to override he inline important is with JavaScript.

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite that jquery with JavaScript. I understand that jquery is concise JavaScript. So, I guess my question would be, what would be the long JavaScript way of writing that jquery?

Answer (score 1):

true jquery code is :

```
$("div.row").attr("style", "color:red !important");
```

also, this code is reset the inline style.

```
$("div.row").attr("style", "");
```

Comment: I've tried that too. I think it is my environment that prevents this from working. I know that jquery works because I have used it for other purposes, but it's this particular code that won't work.

Comment: Above code is very similar to what I have for inline.

Comment: `$("div.row").attr("style", "");`  this code is reset the inline style.

Comment: I tried that too. My work environment forces me to use a browser CodePen does not support. I will check it when I get home! Thanks!

Comment: if was helpful, please accept the my answer also :)

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but adding "div" in front of ".row" is something that I had already tried and did not work from my work environment. I was looking for another method.